# How to display image in Data table of lightning component

Tags: lightning

I am using data table in lightning component.I am referring one column in data table as formula field.That formula field returns image of text type.When i display that field in Lightning component, the image is not displaying.Instead it is displaying the URL. Can anyone help on this issue.
can we display images on the datatable?

### Following code i am using to display the columns in data table.

### Component:

```
<lightning:datatable columns="{!v.columns}"
                     data="{!v.data}"
                     keyField="Id"                                                        
                     hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
```

### Controller code:

```
component.set('v.columns', [
            { label: 'formulafield', fieldName: 'formulafield__c', type: 'text', initialWidth: 350, editable: false, sortable :true }, 
        ]);
```

### Formula field:

```
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(field1)),
IF(field2 >= TODAY(), 
IMAGE("/resource/name","some text",10,10), 
IMAGE("/resource/name1","some text",10,10)),IMAGE("/resource/name2","some text",10,10))
```

### out put in the lightning component:

```
<img src="/resource/name" alt="some text" style="height:10px; width:10px;" border="0"/>
```

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lKqxQAE